# Token only accessible by backend on some requests but not others

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I have an Express.js backend, and a Deno Fresh frontend. The frontend has a simple HTML login form which sends a request to the backend:

```
<form method="POST" action={`${BASE_URL}/api/login`}>
          <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input
              type="email"
              class="form-control"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="name@example.com"
            />
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-floating">
            <input
              type="password"
              class="form-control"
              id="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            <label for="password">Password</label>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 my-2" action="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
```

${BASE_URL} is `https://api.mydomain.com`

Here is the Express.js route that handles the request:

```
Router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  // Validate parameters
  if (!email || !password) return res.status(400).send("Bad Request");

  let result;
  try {
    result = await pgService.login(email, password);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: err.message, success: false });
  }

  res.cookie("token", result.token, {
    maxAge: 3600 * 1000,
    //httpOnly: false,
    domain: ".mydomain.com",
    secure: true,
  });

  if (req.accepts("html")) {
    return res.redirect(`http://${DOMAIN}/#login-success`);
  }
  return res.status(200).json(result);
});
```

${DOMAIN} is "ca.mydomain.com"

This works, filling out the login form and I can see the cookie in my Browser's devtools.  The issue is when making subsequent requests to the backend.

I have a simple logging middleware which logs details about incoming requests to stdout. Here is a sample of the output:

```
{"timestamp":"2023-10-25T16:40:55.811Z","method":"GET","url":"/api/item/SK-200S1","hostname":"127.0.0.1","ip":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","token":""}
{"timestamp":"2023-10-25T16:40:55.854Z","method":"GET","url":"/api/upcs/SK-200S1","hostname":"127.0.0.1","ip":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","token":""}
{"timestamp":"2023-10-25T16:40:56.095Z","method":"GET","url":"/images/9.png","hostname":"127.0.0.1","ip":"::ffff:127.0.0.1","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImpsY2FydmV0aEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJuYW1lIjoiSm9obvCfkZEiLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJkZWZhdWx0IiwiYWRtaW4iXSwiaWF0IjoxNjk4MjUxNTcyLCJleHAiOjE2OTgyNTUxNzJ9.URzeGPtc0d1ckehhYmS2w5IBupEZXTwZd2G7OeVrr7c"}
```

As you can see, on the requests to routes beginning in /api/, the backend cannot access the token. However, the request to /images/9.png, the backend can read the token.

Here is how the logging middleware tries to read the cookie:

```
token = request.get("X-Access-Token") ?? "request.cookies.token" ?? ""
```

So why does it seem that the backend can only read the token sometimes? The domains match, HTTPS is enabled for front and backend.

I guess I can include some relevant frontend code as well, so you can see how these requests are made:

```
/*[OMITTED IMPORTS]*/
const baseURL = Deno.env.get("BASE_URL");
export const handler: Handlers<Data | null> = {
  async GET(_, ctx) {
    const { partno } = ctx.params;
    if (!partno) return ctx.renderNotFound();

    const resp = await fetch(`${baseURL}/api/item/${partno}`);
    const resp2 = await fetch(`${baseURL}/api/upcs/${partno}`);
    let upcs = [];
    if (!resp.ok) return ctx.renderNotFound();
    if (resp2.ok) {
      upcs = await resp2.json();
    }
    const json = await resp.json();
    json.upcs = upcs;

    return ctx.render(json);
  },
};

export default function Item({ data, url }: PageProps<Data | null>) {
  if (data === null) return <p>404</p>;
  return (
    <>
      <Head />
      <Upper />
      <Navbar />
      <main class="container">
        <Breadcrumb route={url.pathname.replace("item", "products")} />
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img
              src={`${baseURL}/images/${data.id}.png`}
              class="img-fluid image-border"
              alt="Product Image"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1 class="my-3">{data.partno}</h1>
            <p>
              <strong>Size:</strong> {data.size}
              <br />
              <strong>Category:</strong> {data.name}
            </p>
            <p>{data.description}</p>
            <a href="/products" class="btn btn-primary">Go back</a>
            <a href={`${baseURL}/pdf/${data.id}.pdf`} class="btn btn-secondary m-2">
              <img src="/img/clipboard-data.svg" alt="" width="16" height="16"/>
              Specifications
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        {data.availableQty &&
          (
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <table class="table table-borderless stock-table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th colSpan={2}>Stock</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>{data.availableQty}</td>
                      <td style="text-align: right">
                        {data.availableQty > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock"}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        {data.upcs && (
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col bordered">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>UPC</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {data.upcs.map((upc) => {
                    return (
                      <tr>
                        <td>{upc.quantityfactor}</td>
                        <td>{upc.upc}</td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  })}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </main>
      <div class="container">
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am expecting the backend to be able to access the token cookie from all requests, not just certain requests.

Yes, I am using cookie-parser.

Some additional information after further testing:

I have tried modifying the Fresh handler fetch calls to include `{ credentials: "same-origin"}`, but the backend still doesn't see the token.

However, when running both the backend and frontend locally to test, I open `localhost:3070` in my browser and open the dev console to run a fetch request:

```
const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:3072/api/version", { credentials: "include"})
```

Suddenly, the backend can see the token cookie again.

Comment: Have you tried `fetch(<url>, { credentials: 'same-origin' })`? Oh, and if you really are sending the request from one subdomain to another you can give `{ credentials: 'include' }` a shot as well.

Comment: Added some more information regarding your suggestion